# ¿Es normal que python, python3 y ipython no apunta a la misma instalación pero pip3 que instalaciones funcionan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

Intento importar Seaborn en iPython, pero obtengo este error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

Todavía no sé cómo crear entornos para no derrotar mi máquina para él, cosas tontas ... Es por eso que descargo todo con

```
sudo pip3 install XXX
```

Supongo que mi binary de ipython no apunta a la misma instalación de python que ipython (y pip, o como sea que hayas instalado seaborn).

```
mike@mike-thinks:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
mike@mike-thinks:~$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
mike@mike-thinks:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Sin embargo funciona ... Parece extano, no ?

Answer (score 1):

Si has instalado algún paquete usando `pip3` debería funcionar con `python3` o la versión de iPython para Python 3.

```
$ sudo pip3 install seaborn
...
```

En Python 2 no funciona:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import seaborn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named seaborn
>>>
```

Pero sí en Python 3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import seaborn
>>>
```

Asegúrate de que al ejecutar `ipython` esté usando la versión 3 de Python. En mi caso sí es así:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import seaborn

In [2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Si esta usando Anaconda es muy sencillo crear entornos usando `Anaconda prompt` con estas instrucciones puede administrarlos:

Para crear, activar y eliminar un entorno:

```
conda create -n NombreEntorno python=3.4 #Version de python que desea en el entorno

activate NombreEntorno #Para activarlo
deactivate NombreEntorno #Para desactivarlo

conda remove --name NombreEntorno --all #Elimina entorno en su totalidad
```

Una vez activo un entorno especifico lo puede personalizar con los siguientes comandos:

Instalar librerías fácilmente con:

```
conda install NombreLibreria
pip Install NombreLibreria
```

Para actualizar una libreria:

```
conda update NombreLibreria
pip install --upgrade NombreLibreria
```

Para forzar la instalación o actualización de una librería:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade NombreLibreria
```

Activar Jupyter

```
jupyter notebook
```

Es posible administrar los entornos desde la interfaz de Anaconda pero no he tenido buenas experiencias con ello así que casi ni la uso.

Estos son los mas comunes. [Acá](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) esta la documentación con mas comandos en caso de temas mas específicos con relación a los entornos.